# Average number of retweets a user gets on his tweet on twitter

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a list of 5000 twitter user ids, Now, I want to get avg number of retweets/favs a user gets on his tweets.

```
max(total_retweets,total_favs)/total_tweets
```

I also want to get the number of mentions that a user got per tweet he did.

```
total_mentions/total_tweets
```

Approximate numbers to these is also fine, given the rate limitations of Twitter apis.

Can somebody suggest a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to use [Tweepy user_timeline](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline) which will return you at max 100 tweets/retweets from the timeline, assuming that that many tweets are available to return.

Do not forget to turn on the `include_rts` switch when calling `api.user_timeline`, else you will not get any retweets in the response.

As for calculating `user_mention` counts, afaik, there is no direct method in Tweepy API but you can manually parse the JSON response that you obtain from above timeline call and calculate counts.